# Convert a `dict[str, list[any]]` into a binary `pandas.DataFrame`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dictionary

```py
d = {
    "anna": ["apple", "strawberry", "banana"],
    "bob": ["strawberry", "banana", "peach"],
    "chris": ["apple", "banana", "peach", "mango"]
}
```

and I want to convert it into the following `pandas.DataFrame`

```py
       apple banana mango peach strawberry
anna       1      1     0     0          1
bob        0      1     0     1          1
chris      1      1     1     1          0
```

It is not very complicated to implement in Python (see below), but I was wondering if there is already something in `pandas` to do it automatically (or if the implementation below can be optimized)

Thanks in advance!

---

**Python current implementation**

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {
    "anna": ["apple", "strawberry", "banana"],
    "bob": ["strawberry", "banana", "peach"],
    "chris": ["apple", "banana", "peach", "mango"]
}
fruits = sorted(set(np.hstack(d.values())))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=fruits)
for client, client_fruits in d.items():
    s = pd.Series({
        fruit: fruit in client_fruits for fruit in fruits
    }).astype(int)
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({client: s}).T])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies):

```
out = pd.Series({k: '|'.join(v) for k,v in d.items()}).str.get_dummies()
```

Or [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
out = (pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').stack())
         .groupby(level=0).max()
       )
```

Or with a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
out = pd.crosstab(*zip(*((k,v) for k,l in d.items() for v in l))).clip(upper=1)
```

Output:

```
       apple  banana  mango  peach  strawberry
anna       1       1      0      0           1
bob        0       1      0      1           1
chris      1       1      1      1           0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({k:v}) for k,v in d.items()],axis=1).stack().droplevel(0)
pd.crosstab(df1.index,df1)
```

out

```
col_0  apple  banana  mango  peach  strawberry
row_0                                         
anna       1       1      0      0           1
bob        0       1      0      1           1
chris      1       1      1      1           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join()` on a Series.

```
pd.Series(d).str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```

Output:

```
       apple  banana  mango  peach  strawberry
anna       1       1      0      0           1
bob        0       1      0      1           1
chris      1       1      1      1           0
```